# ERC721 "NFT" with ImageURL[] instead of single ImageURL

Tags: blockchain, nft

I am looking to create algorithmic NFT's that are built from multiple images. Rather than layering the images for all combinations and then storing all permutations I'd like to send an array of image url's and then simply layer those images based on the order they're stored in the array. Is this possible within current token standards and nft viewer api's?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works but it depends on the situation.
For example, if you want to mint your own NFT tokens, not others, it is a good method to save time and code quantity.
But, if others mint NFT tokens, they cannot be used because it is not sequential and we do not know the ownership of the NFT token.